# Subtract value of a column from previous value of another column in sql

Tags: sql

I want to have column where the value of a subtraction will get stored. Subtraction should happen between value of a column and previous value of another column.

Below is the example:

| Customer ID | Ship date | Supplydate | Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76868773 | 10/15/2018 0:00 | 12/10/2018 0:00 | -4 |
| 76868773 | 12/06/2018 0:00 | 01/31/2019 0:00 | 21 |
| 76868773 | 02/21/2019 0:00 | 04/18/2019 0:00 | 7 |
| 76868773 | 04/25/2019 0:00 | 06/20/2019 0:00 | 7 |
| 76868773 | 06/27/2019 0:00 | 08/22/2019 0:00 | 7 |
| 76868773 | 08/29/2019 0:00 | 10/24/2019 0:00 | 33 |
| 76868773 | 11/26/2019 0:00 | 01/21/2020 0:00 | 9 |
| 76868773 | 01/30/2020 0:00 | 03/26/2020 0:00 | 11 |
| 76868773 | 04/06/2020 0:00 | 06/01/2020 0:00 | 0 |
| 76868773 | 06/01/2020 0:00 | 07/27/2020 0:00 | 2 |
| 76868773 | 07/29/2020 0:00 | 09/23/2020 0:00 | 8 |

Here we have customer ID, for each customer ID the gap should be calculated like shipdate-previous supplydate.. just like 2nd ship date 12/6/2018 minus previous supply date that is 12/10/2018, so gap should be -4.

You can refer to the above link to get the sample data..

Comment: What dbs are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()` windows function.
Assuming that you are using SQL Server.

```
Create table and insert statements:

 create table customer_shipping(Customer_ID int, Ship_date date, Supply_date date);
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'10/15/2018 0:00','12/10/2018 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'12/06/2018 0:00','01/31/2019 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'02/21/2019 0:00','04/18/2019 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'04/25/2019 0:00','06/20/2019 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'06/27/2019 0:00','08/22/2019 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'08/29/2019 0:00','10/24/2019 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'11/26/2019 0:00','01/21/2020 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'01/30/2020 0:00','03/26/2020 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'04/06/2020 0:00','06/01/2020 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'06/01/2020 0:00','07/27/2020 0:00');
 insert into customer_shipping values(76868773  ,'07/29/2020 0:00','09/23/2020 0:00');
```

Query:

```
 select *, datediff(day,supply_date,lead(ship_date)over(partition by customer_id order by ship_date))gap 
 from customer_shipping
```

Output:

| Customer_ID | Ship_date | Supply_date | gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76868773 | 2018-10-15 | 2018-12-10 | -4 |
| 76868773 | 2018-12-06 | 2019-01-31 | 21 |
| 76868773 | 2019-02-21 | 2019-04-18 | 7 |
| 76868773 | 2019-04-25 | 2019-06-20 | 7 |
| 76868773 | 2019-06-27 | 2019-08-22 | 7 |
| 76868773 | 2019-08-29 | 2019-10-24 | 33 |
| 76868773 | 2019-11-26 | 2020-01-21 | 9 |
| 76868773 | 2020-01-30 | 2020-03-26 | 11 |
| 76868773 | 2020-04-06 | 2020-06-01 | 0 |
| 76868773 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-07-27 | 2 |
| 76868773 | 2020-07-29 | 2020-09-23 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0dab048cc9c80907ff081552dca2a39)*

Answer (score 0):

If your database doesn't support LEAD and LAG (earlier versions of MS SQL don't) then you can always use the RANK() OVER() function to give each a unique RANK number and then join the table to itself using an offset on the RANK of 1